# Can a socket on localhost ever receive packets from a previous connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, localhost

Is it ever possible for a TCP socket on localhost to receive packets from a previous connection?  If so, then any program that assumes that this cannot happen is broken.  In particular, any program that assumes that a socket on localhost will never receive any data from anything other than the peer that it is supposed to be connected to is broken.

Edit: I know that this is not *supposed* to happen.  However, I thought that it *could* happen if the previous socket was not in TIME_WAIT for long enough.  The application I am working on requires that this **never happen on localhost** — otherwise, it is subject to an arbitrary code execution vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't messed around with the `TIME_WAIT` setting and left it at its default value, it is twice the Maximum Segment Lifetime (MSL), and it is therefore impossible for a segment from a prior connection to last long enough in the network to be received over a new socket on the same port.

The fact that TCP randomizes the initial sequence numbers is another defence. The sequence number of the stale segment is highly unlikely to fit into the current receive window.

Comment: The Maximum Segment Lifetime is arbitrary.  How do I KNOW that the kernel will handle all traffic in that time on localhost?

Comment: @Demetri The MSL is not arbitrary. It is specified in [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) as 2 minutes.

Comment: I know it is so specified.  I don't know that the kernel's TCP stack is guaranteed to finish all packet processing in this amount of time -- and I need a guarantee here.

Comment: You know that a segment which outlives MSL will be dropped instead of being delivered. That's the whole idea.

Comment: Do kernels actually do this for connections on localhost?

Comment: @Demetri They are required to do it for connections in *all* hosts, by RFC 793.

Answer (score -1):

No, TCP sockets are connection based.

> Once connected, a TCP socket can only send and receive to/from the
>   remote machine. This means that you'll need one TCP socket for each
>   client in your application.

[Source](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/network-socket.php)

Comment: Irrelevant and non-normative reference. The fact that 'TCP sockets are connection-based' doesn't actually answer the question, which is *about* connections.

Comment: The quote answers that. Once connected, they can can ONLY send/receive from that specific remote machine. I don't see how that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You don't appear to understand the purpose of TIME_WAIT, and why it is necessary, and here is not the place to explain it to you. Suffice it to say that it is essential to *provide* the guarantee about connecton integrity that you are merely asserting to be the case. That's why the OP mentions in n his question. If the TIME_WAIT period was too short, the guarantee couldn't be made, and your answer and citation would be false. As it is, they are just hand-waving.